# Use current cell value to calculate and replace in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA in excel and I've tried searching for my question already.

I'm trying to calculate an answer based off the value of the cell and have the calculated value replace the current value upon macro execution. For example if A2 has an initial value of 30 I'd like too replace A2 with =A2*3 so that A2 would read 90 as its new value.

Is there any way to do this without having to copy and paste everything somewhere else first?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes. This is doable. You could use the `Worksheet_Change` event, but that might be more cumbersome. I'll propose a different method that will require you to run the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. First, make sure you have selected at least one cell, and then run the macro from the macros menu:

```
Sub MultiplyBy30()
Dim rng as Range
Dim cl as Range

Set rng = Range(Selection.Address)

For each cl in rng.Cells
    If IsNumeric(cl.Value) And Len(cl.Value) > 0 Then
    cl.Formula = "=" & cl.Value & "*30"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Right now it's showing 123*30 rather as a string than the value 3690. Thanks for the quick response earlier.

Comment: I made an edit (possibly after you first tried it) to include the `"="` in the formula. That should fix it :)

Comment: Thanks! It's perfect. I hope you have a great day!